# How to access server on local network using my public internet IP address?

Tags: php, ip, lan

I have a local server on my local LAN running as a web server.

How can I access sites on that server with my public IP rather than my local network IP?

So when I echo "**$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']**" from a PHP script I get my internet address not 192.168.xx.xx

Comment: Is this a duplicate? 
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php

* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php

Comment: You state your server is local, therefore it will not be able to be accessed from an external IP

Comment: Besides that I actually don't get what you want to achive? Just in one sentence: You are trying to get the ip-Adress of the visitor and show/use it, right?

Comment: @Haudegen No it is not a duplicate. I' know how to get the visitor address what I'm looking for is different. I'm developing a new software which behaves according to visitor's country (determined from his/her IP address). So, I want to test it before uploading to the production server. Right now I'm just using hard coded value for the IP address in my code. I hope you get it now :)

Comment: Sorry, that I am not understandig this: So, which IP-Adress do you want to get now? :(

Comment: The same IP I get from whatismyip.com for example