# How to get Public IP address of the client

Tags: php

I need to get the public IP address of the client.

I have tried the

```
getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') and also $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

but it returns only the private ip ...

Comment: Are you running the server on your local machine?

Comment: IP addresses are of no real value to a server, since the topology they make sense in relation to is not under the servers control. So addresses cannot be trusted. So what for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the client IP address using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php)

Comment: C'mon man, the duplicate question is almost the exact same wording as your question!

Answer (score 2):

Ive used this:

```
function GetIp(){
//IP ADDRESS
   $ipaddress = '';
if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
   $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
    $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
$AgentIp = $ipaddress;

return $AgentIp;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am looking for the same problem and found great solution API based.

To get the public IP address we can can use the below code:

```
<?php
$ip = file_get_contents('https://api.ipify.org');
echo "My public IP address is: " . $ip;
?>
```

**API Site Url:** `https://www.ipify.org/`

It's too late to asnwer on this but it may be halpful for others.

Comment: It returns server IP instead of Client IP