# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, ip

I am new in computer science and also on this site. I am using php *5.4.** on localhost server and trying to get user ip address something like this

`$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
echo 'Your IP address (using $_SERVER[\'REMOTE_ADDR\']) is ' . $ipaddress . '<br />';`

In output comes something like this:

`Your IP address (using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) is ::1`

if possible give me please secure method to get ip address and prevent any type of attacks with ip address

Comment: `::1` is the 127.0.0.1 in IPv6

Answer (score 1):

You are running the server on your computer so this is the only thing you're going to get. It does basically mean the same as `127.0.0.1`.

If you do run it from a different computer in the network (or the internet), you'll be getting what you expect.

Comment: is `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` secure ?

Comment: How do you defined 'secure'? The variable, will obviously show the proxy IP if the person is using a proxy. There are other variables that could help you get the real IP but that's almost never the case. You can read up on other variables mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15699240/1610183). But as far as  you're concerned, `REMOTE_ADDR` should do just fine.