# Getting current IP of a user while viewing a file on Google docs veiwer

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to match Database stored IP of a user and its current IP viewing a file on google docs , to be able to secure the files.

https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/fileview.php?id=NzItMTQ0NjkxNDE4OC0x-5ffee46bf649c798838efba13a2da96f&embedded=true&location=no

when I return both IPs , the current IP of a user is Google 's IP ,

How can I get user IP not the Google Docs viewer IP ?

Comment: they are presumably on your site with PHP no, what's the problem with the [header](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15699101/)

Comment: if what you are asking, (which I am sure you are), is if they are on site A (you), and they are on site B (anything, google), how do you marry the two, good luck with that one. What if they spin to their right and use the 2nd laptop. Too many edge conditions and too broad

Comment: if they get to site B with an anchor tag click, there is that approach of capture. But that does not solve the problem of them getting to site B otherwise

Comment: now perhaps you need to open this open to the google api `tags` to figure out if there is something there that can help

Comment: the 2nd laptop could be on a different ISP. It simply won't work

Comment: I just want to check if a user is logged in on my site while viewing the file ?!