# How to display visitors country flag in magento header

Tags: php, magento, country-codes

I want to display visitors countryname with the flag , I searched in some forums,they have given the solution using some standard php code 
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in the below forum
[Get the client IP address using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php)

Also they have mentioned, it is not safe using the code.

Can we actually get the ipaddress of the visitors using Mage code? Please advice me

Comment: Is this question is very difficult or no one Knows the answer ?