# Yii2 : set current IP address dynamically in console scriptUrl

Tags: yii2, ip

I want to get current IP address from OS. Required to remove dependancy of hardcoding url path in 'scripUrl' for 'UrlManager' component in console.php so that cron controller can send emails with proper hyperlinks

Comment: There is no reliable way to do this. Host could have multiple interfaces with multiple IPs and multiple domains attached to it. Such shortcuts will give you more trouble than introducing some local config files and configuring this for each host individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yii `Request` component is unavailable in console-app

You'll need to rely on php built in functions

> **From CLI**
>
> **PHP < 5.3.0**
>
> ```
> $myIp= getHostByName(php_uname('n'));
> echo $myIp;
> ```
>
> **PHP >= 5.3.0**
>
> ```
> $myIp = getHostByName(getHostName());
> echo $myIp;
> ```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39684274/374509)

Comment: how can i get the port on which apache server is running, any function in php to get the port number??

Comment: you can't do that with php alone. this is dependent on the setup of your system, environment, services you're using and what not, on most linux machines you can parse trough the output of `system('lsof -'i)` and find what port apache is using