# how to print current user's ip address in php 7.1.1

Tags: php

I am trying to get current users ip address using {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} or {getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')}, in both of the cases i am getting ::1 .
I am using php 7.1.1, can any one help how i can get current ip address of current user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the client IP address using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

If your using your local server it will always be ::1 or the local ip address.

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

will return the ip when its on a server outside of your localnetwork.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` or `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` look to [Get the client IP address using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php)