# Regarding my code for Google Recaptcha

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I'm new to this google Recaptcha thing.

I'm trying to figure out which it doesn't work. I have tried several other code and they doesn't work as well which I have no idea why.

This is my form code

```
<form name="contact_form" method="post" action="functions.php">
 <input type="text" id="fname" name="full_name" placeholder="Full Name" required />
 <input type="number" id="pnumber" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
 <input type="email" id="emailid" name="email_address" placeholder="Email Address" required />
 <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" required></textarea>
 <span><input type="checkbox" id="disclaimerid" class="disclaimerclass" name="agreement" value="Agree" required>I have read and agreed with the <a class="dataPrivacyLink" href="#">(Data Protection and Privacy Policy)</a> of Hello World</span>
 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="--PUBLIC KEY--"></div>
 <input type="submit" name="sendmessage" class="send-message" value="SUBMIT NOW" />
</form>
```

And this is my PHP code

```
<?php
  function post_captcha($user_response) {
       $fields_string = '';
       $fields = array(
        'secret' => '_______________PRIVATE_KEY_______________',
        'response' => $user_response
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}
// Call the function post_captcha
$res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
if (!$res['success']) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA wasn't checked
    echo '<p>Please go back and make sure you check the security CAPTCHA box.</p><br>';
} else {
    // If CAPTCHA is successfully completed...

    // Paste mail function or whatever else you want to happen here!
    $send;
if( isset( $_POST['email_address'] ) )
{
    $send="Your inquiry submitted successfully. we will contact you very soon. ";
    send_message_to_agent( $_POST['full_name'], $_POST['phone_number'], $_POST['email_address'], $_POST['message'] );
}
else
{
    $send="fail";   
}
function send_message_to_agent( $full_name, $phone_number, $email_address, $visiter_message ){

    $to      = 'hello@world.com';
    $subject = 'Hello World';

    $message = '<p>Name : '.$full_name.'</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Phone Number : '.$phone_number.'</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Email Address : '.$email_address.'</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Message : '.$visiter_message.'</p>';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
echo $send;
//die;
}
// Your code here to handle a successful verification
/>
```

Comment: Have you replaced this line with your own private key ? 
"  'secret' => '_______________PRIVATE_KEY_______________',"

Comment: Yes, I have replace this line with my own private key, I just took it out because I'm pasting the code here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to also pass your ipaddress

`$fields = array('secret' => '_______________PRIVATE_KEY_______________',
'response' => $user_response,
'remoteip' => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx //your ip
);`

Comment: @HELLOHK Can you please upvote my answer, someone gives negative review

Comment: It works for a few try then afterwards it stopped work. And I have no idea why.

Comment: You have to fetch your ipaddress dynamically.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Follow this link which will helps to get ipaddress [Ip Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php)

Comment: I did this but it still doesn't want to send :(

'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Comment: Have you debug it properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146821/discussion-between-nirav-joshi-and-hellohk).

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to include the reCAPTCHA API JavaScript library.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

In your form

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="--PUBLIC KEY--"></div>
```

In your post function

```
       $secret = 'SCREAT_KEY';
                //get verify response data
     $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
                $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
                if($responseData->success){
//perform action on success
}
else{
//redirect to login
}
```

Comment: After I add in my send action it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird because after adding in my server ip it works for awhile then now it doesn't want to send again.