# Display IP address on page with HTML

Tags: php, html, ip-address

I am just starting HTML so the mistake I am currently making is probably something really obvious. I found this code that should display the user's IP address on the page, but it doesn't work. Why is this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Palpable Coral</title>
</head>
<body>
Your IP address is: <? echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML itself does not provide a way to retrieve an IP address. The code you show uses PHP to get the IP address and to insert it into the HTML code.

Comment: @t.niese So, how would I do this, then?

Comment: That is not HTML, that is server side code. It looks like php but should be ```<?php echo... ```. You can't get an IP with plain HTML.

Comment: [here](http://jsbin.com/bajubacaju/edit?html,output) , try this js code. its very easy to go with.

Answer (score -2):

i think this link will help you
[Get the client IP address using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php)

or use php like this

< ? php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ? >

Comment: He still need the extension `.php` to get it work and `apache server` ex. `xampp,wamp,lamp`

Comment: if it is in localhost of course xaamp/wamp in needed. Else all of these are preinstaled.